# C# XML download images from links in XML mark

Tags: c#, xml

In my XML file I have mark:

```
 <screens>http://www.bigfoto.com/stones-background.jpg, https://www.bensound.com/bensound-img/betterdays.jpg</screens>
```

and how download images from this links ?

I tryed that:

```
linkToDownload = result.Element("screens").Value.ToString();

            List<string> adress = new List<string>() { linkToDownload };

        foreach (string img in adress)
        {
            var webClient = new WebClient();

            var fname = Path.GetTempFileName();

            await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(img, fname);
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(fname);

            imageList1.Images.Add(bitmap);
            listCount++;

        }
```

Comment: What issue do you have?

Comment: Only first link read.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested code below and worked but this is not asyc. First thing was splitting the list of images into an array then run `GetTempFileName()` and changed "tmp" extension by the extension of the image in the link, so that Bitmap constructor knows what type the content of temp file is, and would be able to create bitmap object.

```
var result = XDocument.Parse("<screens>http://www.bigfoto.com/stones-background.jpg,"
+ "https://www.bensound.com/bensound-img/betterdays.jpg</screens>");
var screens = result.Element("screens");
string[] links = screens==null ? new string[]{} : screens.Value.Split(',');
foreach (string link in links)
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(link);
    var fileName = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetTempFileName(), extension);
    webClient.DownloadFile(link, fileName);
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(fileName);

    //imageList1.Images.Add(bitmap);
    //listCount++;
}
```